# How to create a common IconButton in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Here is my case, 
To create a common icon button, which can be used with different icons whereever.

Here are my steps:

1). create a custom IconButton derived from Button, it has a DefaultImageSource dependency property. Here it is:

```
public class IconButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultImageSourceProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(IconButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));//, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnImageSourceChanged));

    public ImageSource DefaultImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(DefaultImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DefaultImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

2). Create a style for IconButton in project resource where supppose to use this IconButton with this style,

```
        <Style x:Key="IconButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type WpfApplication3:IconButton}">                
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type WpfApplication3:IconButton}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DefaultImageSource}"  Stretch="Uniform" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="imageArt"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="focusEllipse" Fill="Transparent"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="focusEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="#AAFFFFFF"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="focusEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="#AA808080"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="focusEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="#80808080"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

3). Create multi IconButton in my WPF window, and binding them to different icon, but no luck; icons don't show up when openning this window,

```
<Grid>

    <DockPanel>

        <WpfApplication3:IconButton Width="30" Height="30" DefaultImageSource="{DynamicResource RefreshIcon}" Style="{DynamicResource IconButtonTemplate}"></WpfApplication3:IconButton>

        <WpfApplication3:IconButton Width="30" Height="30" DefaultImageSource="{DynamicResource RunIcon}" Style="{DynamicResource IconButtonTemplate}"></WpfApplication3:IconButton>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

It might be issue of the wrong binding for the image resource, but can't figure out with several tries. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see the issue in Binding . Using

```
 <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DefaultImageSource}"  Stretch="Uniform" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="imageArt"/>
```

using **Self** Mode you are trying to Bind **Source** to **DefaultImageSource** property of **Image** Control. And **Image** doesnot have any such property so bang.

Try this

```
 <Image Source="{TemplateBinding DefaultImageSource}"  Stretch="Uniform" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" x:Name="imageArt"/>
```

This will try to bind the **Source** of **Image** to **DefaultImageSource** property of **Button**.

I hope this will help.